# Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined - Angular error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have the following error with my code:

> Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined

When `setTimeout()` is removed, the code works fine. I can't understand why this is happening though `nav` is properly defined.

```
export class LoginStudentPage {

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
  }

  loading: any;

  goToDiary(child){
      this.storage.set('regNo', child);
      this.loading.present();
      setTimeout(function(){
        this.nav.setRoot(TabsNavigationPage);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }, 1500);
  }
}
```

Comment: when the function goToDiary is called?

Comment: use an arrow function as the function you give to setTimeout so the same lexical context is kept and `this` works as you want it to

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine! But I still couldn't understand why it is so. Could you please explain more elaborately, @toskv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @ShafeefOmar check out the duplicate question I linked. it's all about this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function this no longer refers to your class & refers instead to the object **window**. So one of the solutions to solve this issue is by using arrow functions.

```
goToDiary(child){
      this.storage.set('regNo', child);
      this.loading.present();
      setTimeout(_=> {
        this.nav.setRoot(TabsNavigationPage);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }, 1500);
  }
```